# Flutter iOS build errors with flutter_blue

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, flutter-ios-build

have had problems with flutter builds on ios for a few days. I created a bluetooth app with the flutter_blue lib. If I want to run this, I get the following stacktrace. Have the settings iOS Deployment Target correctly set. Reinstall Pods and Flutter framework, clearing the cache unfortunately didn't help.

```
 Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code
    /Users/pce/DevTools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_blue-0.8.0/ios/Classes/FlutterBluePlugin.m:76:34: error: expected identifier or '('
              }>_centralManager.state]];
                                     ^
    /Users/pce/DevTools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_blue-0.8.0/ios/Classes/FlutterBluePlugin.m:77:11: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
              result(data);
              ^
    /Users/pce/DevTools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_blue-0.8.0/ios/Classes/FlutterBluePlugin.m:77:18: error: a parameter list without types is only allowed in a function definition
              result(data);
                     ^
    /Users/pce/DevTools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_blue-0.8.0/ios/Classes/FlutterBluePlugin.m:78:7: error: extraneous closing brace ('}')
          } else {
          ^
    /Users/pce/DevTools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_blue-0.8.0/ios/Classes/FlutterBluePlugin.m:78:9: error: expected identifier or '('
          } else {
            ^
    /Users/pce/DevTools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_blue-0.8.0/ios/Classes/FlutterBluePlugin.m:81:3: error: extraneous closing brace ('}')
      } else if([@"isAvailable" isEqualToString:call.method]) {
      ^
    /Users/pce/DevTools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_blue-0.8.0/ios/Classes/FlutterBluePlugin.m:81:5: error: expected identifier or '('
      } else if([@"isAvailable" isEqualToString:call.method]) {
        ^
    /Users/pce/DevTools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_blue-0.8.0/ios/Classes/FlutterBluePlugin.m:103:5: error: expected identifier or '('
      } else if([@"isOn" isEqualToString:call.method]) {
        ^
    /Users/pce/DevTools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_blue-0.8.0/ios/Classes/FlutterBluePlugin.m:109:5: error: expected identifier or '('
      } else if([@"startScan" isEqualToString:call.method]) {
        ^
    /Users/pce/DevTools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_blue-0.8.0/ios/Classes/FlutterBluePlugin.m:127:5: error: expected identifier or '('
      } else if([@"stopScan" isEqualToString:call.method]) {
        ^
    /Users/pce/DevTools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_blue-0.8.0/ios/Classes/FlutterBluePlugin.m:130:5: error: expected identifier or '('
      } else if([@"getConnectedDevices" isEqualToString:call.method]) {
        ^
    /Users/pce/DevTools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_blue-0.8.0/ios/Classes/FlutterBluePlugin.m:135:5: error: expected identifier or '('
      } else if([@"connect" isEqualToString:call.method]) {
        ^
    /Users/pce/DevTools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_blue-0.8.0/ios/Classes/FlutterBluePlugin.m:152:5: error: expected identifier or '('
      } else if([@"disconnect" isEqualToString:call.method]) {
        ^
    /Users/pce/DevTools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_blue-0.8.0/ios/Classes/FlutterBluePlugin.m:161:5: error: expected identifier or '('
      } else if([@"deviceState" isEqualToString:call.method]) {
        ^
    /Users/pce/DevTools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_blue-0.8.0/ios/Classes/FlutterBluePlugin.m:169:5: error: expected identifier or '('
      } else if([@"discoverServices" isEqualToString:call.method]) {
        ^
    /Users/pce/DevTools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_blue-0.8.0/ios/Classes/FlutterBluePlugin.m:181:5: error: expected identifier or '('
      } else if([@"services" isEqualToString:call.method]) {
        ^
    /Users/pce/DevTools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_blue-0.8.0/ios/Classes/FlutterBluePlugin.m:189:5: error: expected identifier or '('
      } else if([@"readCharacteristic" isEqualToString:call.method]) {
        ^
    /Users/pce/DevTools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_blue-0.8.0/ios/Classes/FlutterBluePlugin.m:204:5: error: expected identifier or '('
      } else if([@"readDescriptor" isEqualToString:call.method]) {
        ^
    /Users/pce/DevTools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_blue-0.8.0/ios/Classes/FlutterBluePlugin.m:220:5: error: expected identifier or '('
      } else if([@"writeCharacteristic" isEqualToString:call.method]) {
        ^
    /Users/pce/DevTools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_blue-0.8.0/ios/Classes/FlutterBluePlugin.m:237:5: error: expected identifier or '('
      } else if([@"writeDescriptor" isEqualToString:call.method]) {
        ^
    fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
    1 warning and 20 errors generated.
```

My dependencies

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:

  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  floor: ^1.0.1
  flutter_svg: ^0.22.0

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  url_launcher: ^6.0.3
  native_pdf_view: ^4.0.1
  flutter_blue: any
  path_provider: ^2.0.2
  permission_handler: ^7.1.0
  sizer: ^2.0.13
  share: ^2.0.1
  intl: ^0.17.0
  open_file: ^3.2.1
  fl_chart: ^0.36.1
  hexcolor: ^2.0.3
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.7
  pdf: ^3.4.2
  printing: ^5.4.3
  toggle_switch: ^1.2.0
  uri_to_file: ^0.1.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  floor_generator: ^1.0.1 # flutter packages pub run build_runner build
  build_runner: ^1.7.3
  change_app_package_name: ^1.0.0 # flutter pub run change_app_package_name:main com.new.package.name
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.9.1"
  flutter_native_splash: ^1.1.9
```

flutter doctor output

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 2.6.0-12.0.pre.436, on macOS 11.5.2 20G95 darwin-arm, locale de-DE)
    • Flutter version 2.6.0-12.0.pre.436 at /Users/pce/DevTools/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 062d1e5c20 (2 hours ago), 2021-10-21 02:48:04 -0400
    • Engine revision d4e2709791
    • Dart version 2.15.0 (build 2.15.0-233.0.dev)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/pce/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6916264)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.0)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6916264)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.60.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension can be installed from:
       https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • iPhone von PCE (mobile) • ios            • iOS 14.6 18F72
    • iPhone 13 (mobile)      • 4DFD75F5-4594-44BC-B063-1DE284142B94 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-15-0 (simulator)
    • Chrome (web)            • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use flutter_blue: ^0.8.0
This might solve your problem.